# Vote system using double tap

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to implement a vote system when users double tap the image. When the user double taps the image the vote count adds one and saves to parse.  In my cell I have

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        //postsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        bottomBlurView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.698, blue: 0.792, alpha: 0.75)
        votesLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("onDoubleTap:"))
        gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

        heartIcon?.hidden = true
        //profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.height / 2

    }


func onDoubleTap (sender: AnyObject) {
        if self.complition != nil
        {
            self.complition!()
        }
        heartIcon?.hidden = false
        heartIcon?.alpha = 1.0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay:1.0, options:nil, animations: {
            self.heartIcon?.alpha = 0
            }, completion: {
                (value:Bool) in
                self.heartIcon?.hidden = true
        })
    }

    }
```

and in my collection view controller I have

```
func onDoubleTap (indexPath:NSIndexPath)
{
    let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NewCollectionViewCell

    let object = self.votes[indexPath.row]

    if let likes = object["votes"] as? Int
    {
        object["votes"] = likes + 1
        object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{ (success:Bool,error:NSError?) -> Void in
            println("Data saved")

        }
        cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(likes + 1)"
                }
    else
    {
        object["votes"] = 1
        object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{ (success:Bool,error:NSError?) -> Void in
            println("Data saved")
        }
        cell.votesLabel?.text = "1"
    }

}
```

However this does not add one and does not save to parse. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please use breakpoints and tell us which is the error

Comment: There is no error. It just does not work.

Comment: If it doesn't work, there's an error

Comment: ok yes Is it weird having two onDoubleTap Functions but different class?ok I put a breakpoint in the collection view (second piece of code)in the question and it looks like it is not called.

Comment: Where are you calling the collection view's `onDoubleTap`? That seems to be the issue

Comment: I am not calling it from anywhere. its not wrapped in, just in the collection class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85221/discussion-between-dante-puglisi-and-satsuki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the first `onDoubleTap` in your collectionView's `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and configure it there.